# Mongoose claims I have extra / in DB uri though I do not think I do

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I was forced to move DB clusters so I have a new connection string and no actual code changes in the application were made.

When I try to start the application I get the below error message using the following connection string(s), I've included my old one and new one. This cluster is running on Mongo Atlas as a M10 cluster.

Old

`mongodb+srv://<myusername>:<mypassword>@production-m0-<account ID?>.mongodb.net`

New
`mongodb+srv://<myusername>:<mypassword>@production.<account ID?>.mongodb.net`

Error message/log

```
/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:346
          throw err;
          ^

MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '/'
    at Function.create (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
    at validateDatabaseName (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/db_ops.js:728:24)
    at new Db (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:182:3)
    at MongoClient.db (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:237:14)
    at /opt/node_app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:564:62
    at /opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:410:17
    at executeCallback (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:402:9)
    at /opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:286:5
    at connectCallback (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:265:5)
    at /opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:417:5
    at ReplSet.connectHandler (/opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/replset.js:343:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ReplSet.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at /opt/node_app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:786:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Code used in application

```
const dbString =`${config.db}/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
mongoose.connect(dbString, { autoReconnect: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (!err) console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully.')
});
```

EDIT as requested combined UrI

`mongodb+srv://<myusername>:<mypassword>@production.<account ID?>.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Figure out the actual URI used, add it to your question with the password redacted. MongoDB URI parsing is specified to be performed in an unconventional manner which can produce unexpected error reporting.

Comment: @D.SM If you check the OP you will see I have provided the actual uri both from my old cluster and my new one. I redacted username/password/accountID already

Comment: You provided pieces of the URI. Add the full combined one.

Comment: @D.SM added in an edit to OP

Comment: I'm guessing your password contains unescaped characters like /.

Comment: @D.SM Password contains upper and lower case letters with numbers mixed in, no special characters

Comment: I should note that the username and password for both are the same, ie the username and password both worked with the old cluster/uri

Comment: `mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@production.accountID.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority` is a valid URI. Try this in your application.

Comment: @D.SM Umm? Isn't that already what I have? I don't see a difference?

Comment: My suggested URI does not have angle brackets or question marks.

Comment: @D.SM My actual URI doesn't have angle brackets in it, in my OP I showed it like Mongo Atlas does with the brackets. As for question marks, I see the same one in your example as in mine. Difference is I have one inside the angle brackets around the account id since I wasn't sure that was an account ID. Pretty much if it is inside angle brackets in my provided example then in my actual it has the correct values.

Comment: Since you, understandably, have not provided the actual URI that you are using, I am asking you to try the URI exactly as I typed it and report with the results.

Comment: @D.SM What I am saying is we have the exact same URI, and trying yours is like trying mine, yours === mine

Comment: Type my URI exactly as I typed it. It's not the same as either your actual URI or your placeholdered URI.

Comment: @D.SM What is the difference??? Minus taking out angle brackets which my actual one doesn't have, and taking out the question mark after account ID, what is the difference? I need to know what to change to try something new.